# One of the categories is not showing up in the navigation menu

Tags: magento2, navigation

I'm not sure why the category marked in the image below isn't showing in the storefront.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to confirm following things.

1. Category Must be **Enable**.
2. Category Must be **set "Include In Menu"**
3. Check, **store level configuration** for the same category, is that same as above.
4. Save the category and do caching and re-indexing one's.
5. If you use custom **mega menu extension,** then assign the category into that properly to show on front-end.

Comment: Thanks, where to check store level configuration?

Comment: @CodeForGood you need to check Top left corner, same like other entity product etc.

Comment: I checked, everything seems correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **store level configuration** as mentioned in below screenshot
[image: Please check store level option as mentioned in below screenshot]

Comment: Site is always in "Default Store View" Scope. Why is the menu item still not appearing in the frontend?

Comment: Also check "Enable Category" & "Include In Menu" option enable or not for specific store

Comment: Checked that both are enabled. We have only one store running on this site. What else can I try? Thanks

Comment: I would like to give you access to my site if you are willing to have a look at Magento settings? Please email me at pramodraam@gmail.com to start the communication.